# Disable a function from executing in post.php

Tags: admin, save-post

I have a function that seems to execute on saving a post (post.php) and I would to disable it from executing then. I don't know how to specify that? I could check if is_admin, but that would disable the function from working at all when I'm logged in. I'd like to only disable it when I'm in the dashboard saving/updating the post.

Comment: Please provide additional details on your question. Which function do you want to disable?

Comment: Sounds as though you have something hooked to one of the numerous hooks that fire when you save a post. Without more information, and _your code_, it isn't going to be possible to provide much of an answer.

Comment: Is there a conditional tag for saving a post so I can exclude the function from executing then?